# Android AChartEngine - How to hide display of value when pie chart slice is 0%

Tags: java, android, achartengine

Am working on an Android App which displays a piechart using AChartEngine. The piechart displays 8 different values. Sometimes one of the value is 100% and the rest are 0%. In such a case, seven 0% values are displayed on the pie chart. This doesn't look nice as you can see here:

[image: here]
<sub>(source: [zoho.com](https://docs.zoho.com/viewembeddoc.do?docId=o319t178cd6596bd94d8abd9bbb3e8074b823&ftype=image&filename=piechart_screenshot.png&imgWidth=770&imgHeight=515&version=1.0))</sub>

How do I prevent display of the value when it is 0% ?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to not add the 0 values. If you do add them then they exist and they must be displayed.